# update record in database using jdatabase

Tags: joomla3.0

How do to use jdatabase to update a record in Joomla3. Here is what i have so far.

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->update('#__test AS h');
$query->set('h.name = 'apple', h.description= 'orange', h.url = 'bannana'');
$query->where('h.id=1');    
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Am i missing something simple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just spent the day banging my head against the wall with this too. You're very close, but you just need some minor tweaks.

```
$query->set('h.name = 'apple', h.description= 'orange', h.url = 'bannana'');
```

should be (note the quotes):

```
$query->set('h.name = "apple", h.description= "orange", h.url = "bannana"');
```

Also:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
```

will throw a "Strict Standards" warning in developer mode. Just remove the ampersand.

The missing piece:

```
try {
    $result = $db->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

P.S. I realize this answer is a bit late so I hope that you've solved your problem by now. I am posting this answer for those who come across it later and can't find the solution in Joomla's shitty documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the response Joseph. I did eventually get it working, worthwhile also using Joomlas quote function like this $query->set('h.name = $db->quote("apple"), h.description= $db->quote("orange"), h.url = $db->quote("bannana")');