# Joomla 3.1 Database update query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla3.0

Recently I was making an upload component for joomla 3.1 back-end.
based on [How to Save Uploaded File's Name on Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927464/how-to-save-uploaded-files-name-on-database)
I was successful in moving the file to the hard-drive,
however I just cant get the update query to work based on the posted post above.

I don't get any SQL errors and saving works, but somehow ignores the database part.

I really hope I missed something obvious. (btw I don't know the joomla way of queries very well)

In `phpmyadmin` the following query works:

```
UPDATE hmdq7_mysites_projects
SET project_file = 'test'
WHERE id IN (3);
```

I have tried the following queries:

```
$id = JRequest::getVar('id');
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();  
$sql = "UPDATE hmdq7_mysites_projects 
        SET project_file =' " . $filename. "' 
        WHERE id IN (".$id.");";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$db->query();
```

---

```
$colum = "project_file";
$id = JRequest::getVar('id');
$data = JRequest::getVar( 'jform', null, 'post', 'array' );
$data['project_file'] = strtolower( $file['name']['project_file'] ); 

$db =& JFactory::getDBO();   
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->update('#__mysites_projects');
$query->set($column.' = '.$db->quote($data));
$query->where('id'.'='.$db->quote($id));             
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

Here is the current code:

```
class MysitesControllerProject extends JControllerForm
{

    function __construct() {
        $this->view_list = 'projects';
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function save(){
        // ---------------------------- Uploading the file ---------------------
        // Neccesary libraries and variables
        jimport( 'joomla.filesystem.folder' );
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

        $path= JPATH_SITE . DS . "images";
        // Create the gonewsleter folder if not exists in images folder
        if ( !JFolder::exists(JPATH_SITE . "/images"  ) ) {
            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage( $path , 'blue');
        }

        // Get the file data array from the request.
        $file = JRequest::getVar( 'jform', null, 'files', 'array' );

        // Make the file name safe.
        $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']['project_file']);

        // Move the uploaded file into a permanent location.
        if ( $filename != '' ) {
            // Make sure that the full file path is safe.
            $filepath = JPath::clean( JPATH_SITE . "/images/" .  $filename );

            // Move the uploaded file.
            JFile::upload( $file['tmp_name']['project_file'], $filepath );

            $colum = "project_file";
            $id = JRequest::getVar('id');
            $data = JRequest::getVar( 'jform', null, 'post', 'array' );
            $data['project_file'] = strtolower( $file['name']['project_file'] ); 

             $db =& JFactory::getDBO();   
             $query = $db->getQuery(true);
             $query->update('#__mysites_projects');
             $query->set($column.' = '.$db->quote($data));
             $query->where('id'.'='.$db->quote($id));             
             $db->setQuery($query);
             $db->query(); 


        }

        // ---------------------------- File Upload Ends ------------------------

        JRequest::setVar('jform', $data );

        return parent::save();
    }
```

Comment: Solved: after reviewing the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531603/update-record-in-database-using-jdatabase?rq=1. i made up some fixed test values. turns out query is correct but $data varible in query had no data. $data['project_file'] = strtolower( $file['name']['project_file'] );  removed the array from first part and varible worked.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in comments. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved: after reviewing the post [update record in database using jdatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531603/update-record-in-database-using-jdatabase?rq=1) I made up some fixed test values. It turns out the query is correct but `$data` variable in the query had no data. `$data['project_file'] = strtolower( $file['name']['project_file'] );` removed the array from first part and variable worked.